# How to start Zendesk chat after receiving a coin base webhook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, coinbase-api, zendesk

I hope you all are well.
Currently, I'm working on a website where I'm selling game items like gold and characters. I'm receiving payment through Coinbase. I want to send a message in [Zendesk](https://www.zendesk.com/) chatbox from the user who paid, after successful payment on Coinbase.
**Tech I'm using**

- Django for backend
- HTML, CSS and JS for front-end

**Things I've done so far**

1. I've managed to receive money in my Coinbase account and Coinbase redirects to my website after successful payment. I'm doing all this by the following code.

```
def buy_osrs(request):
    obj = Setting.objects.first()
    osrs_price = getattr(obj, "osrs_price")
    osrs_fee = getattr(obj, "osrs_fee")
    form = OSRSForm()
    site = get_current_site(request).domain
    payment_success = f"https://{site}/payment/"
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = OSRSForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            total = float(form.cleaned_data.get("osrs_numbers")) * osrs_price + osrs_fee
            charge_info = {
                "name": "My Website",
                "description": "My Website Description",
                "local_price": {"amount": total, "currency": "USD"},
                "pricing_type": "fixed_price",
                "metadata": {"rsn": form.cleaned_data.get("rsn"), "email": form.cleaned_data.get("email")},
                "redirect_url": payment_success,
            }
            charge = client.charge.create(**charge_info)
            return redirect(charge.get("hosted_url"))
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "osrs_price": osrs_price,
        "osrs_fee": osrs_fee,
    }
    return render(request, "main/buy_osrs.html", context)
```

2. I've managed to set up and receive webhooks, which change my database according to the response it gets from Coinbase.

```
@csrf_exempt
def coinbase_webhook(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # event payload
        request_data = request.body.decode("utf-8")
        # webhook signature
        request_sig = request.headers.get("X-CC-Webhook-Signature")

        try:
            # signature verification and event object construction
            event = Webhook.construct_event(request_data, request_sig, settings.SECRET_KEY)

            obj, created = CoinbaseOrder.objects.get_or_create(order_id=event.id, code=event.data.code)
            if event.type == "charge:pending":
                obj.status = "Pending Confirmation"
                obj.save()
                
            elif event.type == "charge:confirmed":
                obj.status = "Payment Confirmed"
                obj.save()

            elif event.type == "charge:delayed":
                obj.status = "Payment Delayed"
                obj.save()

            elif event.type == "charge:resolved":
                obj.status = "Payment Resolved"
                obj.save()

            elif event.type == "charge:failed":
                obj.status = "Payment Failed"
                obj.save()

        except (WebhookInvalidPayload, SignatureVerificationError) as e:
            return str(e), 400

    return HttpResponse()
```

**Things that I want** 
Now my requirement is whenever `event.type == "charge:confirmed"` happen, an automatic message should be sent in Zendesk live chatbox from end-user saying, Hi, I'm ABC. I've paid you XYZ amount. 
I think this is not possible through webhook, I have to use jquery or some other technology for this. So kindly guide me what's the best strategy